# Should it be 'Is there are' or 'are there'?

Tags: grammar, phrases, tenses, there-is

I am confused between 'Is there are' and 'are there' which one of them is correct? For example 'Is there are/are there any time before 1 o'clock?' Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine any scenario where "is there are" would be used. As for the concrete example you proposed, "is there any time" would be correct, as time is uncountable and uncountable nouns are always preceded by "is".

> Is there any water?
>   Is there any air?
>   Is there any time?

**EDIT:**

As for countable nouns, *is* precedes singular nouns and *are* precedes plural nouns, for example:

> Is there any milk in the fridge? (singular, countable)
>   Are there any people in the park? (plural, countable)

Now, as for your example in the comments section, where you ask whether the following is correct:

> Is there a dog in the park?

Technically it is correct and there are various scenarios where this would be preferred, but generally I'd suggest going for the more usual:

> Are there any dogs in the park?

Comment: @Saras: And more specifically, you want 'Is there any time before 1 o'clock?' and, if these are fixed time slots, you could possibly say 'Are there any times before 1 o'clock?'

Comment: @RiMMER Ψ so 'Are there' is the correct use? i.e. 'Are there any people at the park?' and 'Is there' for uncountable? - 'Is there a dog at the park?'

Comment: @Saras: edited to answer your further questions